# Import only a specific node type

Tags: datagrab, xml

Is there a way to import a specific type of content via datagrab (@type - eg, Press Release)? I tried adding several variations of /cmPublishImport/content?type="Press Release" on an xml import with no avail? Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the cmPublishImport path you're referring to is. Is that the URL of another system you're importing from? If so, then any sort of filtering by type would be a function of that system, not EE. As far as I know there's no way to filter within DataGrab. In some cases I've found it necessary to write a PHP script outside of EE to read an XML feed and manipulate it, and point DataGrab to that instead, so that might be an option here.